# What is the best solution for a Phonegap project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, mobile, cordova

I am looking for some experienced developers on Phonegap.

The company where I work, would like to have an Hybrid App using Phonegap.

I have made some web projects, but I've never used any MVC Framework. I practically do all my projects using JavaScript, JQuery, CSS and HTML.

To start this Phonegap project I am making some Internet searching trying to find the best solution to get a well functional App, but apparently there is just too much information:

**Mobile Frameworks**

- JQuery Mobile
- Sencha Touch
- Kendo UI
- ...

**MVC Frameworks**

- Backbone
- Angularjs
- Emberjs
- ...

**Templates**

- Mustache
- Topcoat
- ...

I have no experience using any of this technologies, so I don't mind to start with one of them.
I am looking for the best solution to make an App that look as native as possible.

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 8):

Try the Telerik AppBuilder IDE(Cloud IDE) where you dont need to worry about adding SDKs etc which helps to build very good hybrid applications...some sample applications are also available.

http://www.telerik.com/appbuilder

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the app you want to build.

I worked with Sencha Touch and jQuery Mobile.

**Sencha Touch:**

- You have to write more JavaScript Code and just a little bit of HTML.
- MVC structured
- A lot of features
- Takes long time to learn
- ...

**jQuery Mobile**

- Your Experience with jQuery will help you
- Lot of HTML and just a little bit JavaScript to write an simple app
- You have to define your own structure
- fast to learn
- ...

My decision was Sencha Touch because of its features.

But what is your app about? I think some details will help us giving more advice.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, It's pretty basic. The user fill a form, this form will send it to the server, the server will process the information and send back a result, that will be display on the app. I don't even need to implement any of the APIs like camera, accelerometer, etc.

Comment: Hmm that's really simple. I think a small jQuery Mobile App would be enough. Design the UI with it and do the Backend job using plain JavaScript. It's not that complicated. POST data with ajax and work on the callback data.

Comment: But it wouldn't be a problem with Sencha Touch too. But you have to learn a lot of Sencha Touch Basics to achieve that app. When you are going to never write a complex Hybrid App again, that's too much learning time i think, but when you are going to write much more apps, i would choose Sencha Touch.

Comment: Ya you're right, I better start with Sencha. Looks really robust

Answer (score 1):

Out of all those mobile frameworks you've mentioned, I found [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/learn/touch/) as a better option. I haven't used Kendo UI but used Jquery Mobile. It is kind of sluggish when it comes to page transitioning. Sencha Touch comes very handy when you want to build hybrid apps that use MVC architecture.

http://www.sencha.com/learn/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap/

I usually use Sencha Touch to build my app and use PhoneGap in order to access native features. So, the combo of PhoneGap + Sencha Touch is pretty cool.